# A Question about Weak Convergence of a Ratio

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

I have a question regarding convergence in distribution, which arose during one of my research works. First, let me describe the setup a bit:

$\textbf{Description of the Problem}$:

Suppose that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are two $\textbf{independent}$ sequences of random variables, such that $\sqrt{n} X_n \xrightarrow{d} F$ and $\sqrt{n}Y_n \xrightarrow{d} F$, where $F$ is a **continuous** probability distribution. As a consequence, $\frac{X_n}{Y_n} \xrightarrow{d} \frac{X}{Y}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent observations drawn from $F$.

Now, suppose that $W_n$ and $Z_n$ are two sequences of random variables such that the joint sequences $(X_n,W_n)$ and $(Y_n,Z_n)$ are independent with each other ($X_n$ and $W_n$ may be dependent, and similarly, $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ may be dependent). Also, assume that $X_n - W_n \xrightarrow{d} 0$ and $Y_n - Z_n \xrightarrow{d} 0$.

$\textbf{My Question}$:

Does the above setting imply that:
$$\frac{W_n}{Z_n}\xrightarrow{d} \frac{X}{Y}~?$$

In my research, $F$ is the standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$, so I would also be happy if you can prove the claim with this additional assumption. And in case the claim is false, are there other technical assumptions which make it true?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false given your assumptions. A simple counterexample is already given. To induce the desired result, one can strengthen the assumption to $\sqrt{n}(W_n-X_n) \to_d 0$ and $\sqrt{n}(Z_n-Y_n) \to_d 0$. Then one can show that (by e.g. Portmanteau lemma)
$$
\sqrt{n}(X_n - W_n) \to_d 0 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{n}(X_n - W_n) \to_p 0.
$$ Thus, one can conclude that
$$
\sqrt{n}W_n = \sqrt{n}X_n +\sqrt{n} (W_n - X_n) \to_d F.
$$ This is because $A_n \to_d A$ and $B_n \to_p c$ implies $(A_n,B_n) \to_d (A,c)$. Then, continuous mapping theorem gives $A_n + B_n \to_d A+c$. In the same spirit, we have $Z_n \to_d F$, and hence $(W_n, Z_n) \to_d (X,Y)$ where $X,Y\sim F$ and $X\perp \!\!\!\perp Y.$ Continuous mapping theorem gives
$$
\frac{W_n}{Z_n}\to_d \frac{X}{Y}
$$as wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but note that I am assuming that $\sqrt{n}X_n$ and $\sqrt{n}Y_n$ are converging weakly to $F$, not $X_n$ and $Y_n$.

Comment: Oops, I misread it. Then you need stronger assumption that $\sqrt{n}(W_n-X_n) \to_d 0$ and $\sqrt{n}(Z_n-Y_n) \to_d 0$. Otherwise, It can even fail that $\sqrt{n}W_n \to_d F.$

Comment: I'm saying that you should strengthen the assumption. A simple example shows that it fails given your original assumption. Take $W_n = 5X_n$ and $Z_n = 3Y_n$ for example.

Comment: Thanks, Song! I got it.

Comment: I hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. I think one simple counterexample is $W_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $Z_n = \frac{2}{n}$. Take $X_n$ and $Y_n$ to be the means of iid random variables with mean $0$ and finite variance.